# VB.NET code for running multiple threads

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

How to I run multiple threads in VB.NET?

Say I need 2 threads - one that prints 100 numbers in a loop and the second one that asks for the user's name and prints it inside a message box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use 2 [BackgroundWorker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/backgroundworker) objects one for each operation that you want to execute. Using the background workers `ProgressChanged` event will ensure that you don't need to marshal the results back to the UI as the [BackgroundWorker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/backgroundworker) already takes care of this for you.